# how to set and get value in google input field via javascript

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromium, input-field

While trying to access the value of input field and setting the value in the input field via javascript getAttribute('value') and setAttribute('value','some value'). It is not working.

Steps to reproduce :

```
document.querySelectorAll('input')[3].getAttribute('value')
->undefined
document.querySelectorAll('input')[3].setAttribute('value','somevalue')
->undefined
```

Comment: This is quite hard to help with, since we don't know for sure which web page you are referring to. Could you please provide the link to the page or a page which is similar, and could work as an example?

Comment: google home page. [link](https://google.com) @Olov